# subtract from value inside dictionary in a list python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and would like to subtract 1 from the value of the key "quality" in all dictionaries from the list

```
list=[{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:5},{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:5},{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:5}]
```

and would like to get

```
list=[{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:4},{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:4},{key1:xx, key2:xx, quality:4}]
```

I tried

```
list=[(i['quality']-1 for i in list]
```

But did not worked

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try to avoid using protect names like `list`, `dict`, or `str` as variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about taking a straightforward approach:

```
>>> l = [{'a':'aa', 'b':'bb', 'quality':5},{'c':'cc', 'd':'dd', 'quality':5},{'e':'ee', 'f':'ff', 'quality':5}]
>>> for item in l:
...     item['quality'] -= 1
... 
>>> l
[{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'quality': 4}, {'c': 'cc', 'quality': 4, 'd': 'dd'}, {'quality': 4, 'e': 'ee', 'f': 'ff'}]
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I had it done like this and was wondering if it would be better using list comprehension... will leave like this!

Comment: If you want to mutate the original data, there is little benefit using a list comprehension.  A simple `for` loop is best for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dict_ in list_:
    dict_['quality'] -= 1
```

There is no advantage to try and one-liner this with a list comprehension.